# C++ list of vectors

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector, stl

I created (or I wanted to create) simple program using list of vectors (from STL).

User specifies numbers of vectors, and then lenght of each vector. Then program asks about each element of vector in for loop.

It crashes after asking user about writing first element.
Program worked fine before I changed datas to STL list and vectors. Earlier i used simple one dimensional table and few loops but such type of program was useless for me.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void writing(int, int);

int main() {
    int n, i, j, m;
    cout << "Give quantity of vectors" << endl;
    cin >> m;
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
        cout << "Give quantity of elements in vector number " << j << endl;
        cin >> n;
        writing(n, m);
    }
    return 0;    
}

void writing(int n, int m) {
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    list<vector<double>> mylist;

    {
        auto it = mylist.begin();
        advance(it, j);
        vector<double>& v = *it;
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i--) {
            cout << "Give the element number " << i << endl;
            cin >> v[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me to find the mistake. I see mistake with `int j` in `writing` function, but error occurs earlier.

Comment: Proper indentation please.

Comment: And [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also please ...

Comment: Your list is empty, but you treat it as if it weren't. Just loop and push a vector into the list each time.

Comment: Also, you dereference ghost elements of your empty list of vectors.

Comment: I have a feeling you want to pass the list in to be partially filled instead of creating a new one each time the function is called.

Comment: @chris It's partially true. My intension is to develop it to let add elements, For example for tables filled with element:  3 4 5 6 7 8 9      4 6 5 43 3 4 2 4 5 6 7  I want to have result   tab[0][4]+tab[1][4]=7+3=10. That's why I want to have One big list of vectors with various lenght. Maybe vector of vectors would be easier to code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **empty** list.

```
list<vector<double>> mylist;
```

Here is an iterator that **can't be dereferenced** because it came from an empty list.

```
auto it = mylist.begin();
```

And here it's dereferenced.

```
vector<double>& v = *it;
```

Comment: Even before that, it's advanced beyond `end()`.

Comment: @chris No it is not.  `advanced()` is called with `int j = 0;`

Comment: @NathanOliver, Good catch. I'm pretty sure OP meant to swap this `j` with the `m` in the call (minus the off-by-one).

Answer (score 0):

Your list is empty and because of that you are trying to access a vector that doesn't exist.  You are then trying to access elements that don't exist in your vector since you never specified the size to the vector.

Comment: If I knew all element of mylist, I would write for example: list<vector<int>> mylist = {{1,2,3}, {4,2,4,0}, {1,5,6,7,8}};    but my list have m elements and each of them has different, yet unknown length.